# Deploy Asp.net core mvc website on Linux hosting (godaddy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, asp.net-core

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022, I've developed a web application with MySQL database and it works fine in Windows hosting and IIS, the problem appeared when I tried to deploy it in GoDaddy Linux host not Windows host. I did all my best with all required steps to deploy it on Linux hosting, when I contacted with godaddy help desk they tolled me that there is no any solution for my problem.
Are there any one published ASP.NET Core MVC on Linux server especially on GoDaddy?

[image: I published my website using this steps then uploaded it on public_html folder]

Comment: Can you add more details about what are the outputs from godaddy?

Comment: When you say "problems appear" you need to describe what those problems are. There are many reasons an application might not work, and it's much more productive to troubleshoot based on the error than for us to take random guesses.

Comment: @Caesar Is there any error message that you see? I believe you can switch to their windows server and it is more convenient to publish .net core on Windows Server. Godaddy use Plesk as their control panel so you can always read this tutorial https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-asp-net-5-on-asphostportal-hosting/

Answer (score 0):

Well, first up, it seems to me a VERY and VERY BEYOND idea to develop on one platform, and worse yet a different OS then what you are deploying to.

Next up, you have to think of a web server JUST like your desktop computer. If you say use some PDF library, then that PDF viewer or library HAS to be installed on your computer for this to work.

Same goes for a web hosting server. If you going to run the .net runtimes on Linux, then you have to setup and install the .net runtimes and system on that Linux server.

You can no more build a program for windows desktop, and THEN decide that program is to now run on a Mac computer, or run on a Android phone.

So, in addition to placing your web site and your .net code that drives the web site on that Linux computer?

You also have to get onto that Linux computer, and install the .net framework, and systems you require.

For example, if you use MySQL as the database? Then that system ALSO has to be installed on that web server.

And if you using SQL server, as the database? Then you have to pick and choose a hosting system that has SQL server installed. Or better yet, pick a hosting plan, and then YOU must develop to the systems and software that is existing on that server.

So, if you decide to develop using PHP and say MySQL? That is VERY unlikely to run on a web site that runs the windows OS.

And if  you decide to use PHP with SQL server? Then you have to ensure that the web hosting server (and plan) has support for PHP, and ALSO has SQL server installed and supported.

Unless you can say install SQL server on that server? And unless you can install the .net runtimes and systems on that server? Then you can't use that hosting plan, or else you go and find a hosting plan that:

Lets you install these systems.
Or
You choose a hosting plan that supports the set of tools you used to develop that web site and code with.

You can't just out of the blue install some windows software on a Mac computer.

And you can't out of the blue develop some software for Linux, and then expect that software to run on windows computers.

So, unless that hosting plan has all the librries, and bits and parts you used to devleop your software with? Then your software not even close to be able to work.

So, check your hosting plan. Does it support SQL server, or MySql? Maybe it only has Postgres SQL support.

Mabe the server does not support PHP - so you can't use that either.

Given that a windows hosting plan on go-daddy is what -- about an extra $2 or $3 dollars per month?

Then why not use and choose and adopt a plan that is windows based in place of Linux based.

The simple matter?

You either buy a hosting plan, check tools and software systems it supports. And then YOU MUST then choose those same developer tools for development.

Or you pick a set of development tools to use, and THEN go find a hosting plan that supports the software and systems you used for development.

However, be it desktop or web development?

You can no more install Android software on windows or Mac. And you can no more install Mac software on a windows desktop.

So, you have to ensure the given computer in question (your web server) has all the software systems and bits and parts installed on that server for YOUR software to run.

After you say been developing for a few years in .net, then I would suggest you get a local Linux computer up and running, and then say spend a month or two, and learning how to run a .net web site on that Linux computer. It certainly can be done, but there is a huge number of bits and parts you have to install, setup, learn to use, and quite a bit more to get this all working.

But you MUST drop this silly idea that any old web server will run any old web site you create.

in fact, EVEN WHEN you say develop using Linux tools, unless that target web server has the same database system, and all of the required systems you used for development? Then you can't even deploy software developed for and on a Linux computer to that Linux web server (unless it supports and has all of the systems and frameworks installed that YOU used to develop your site with).

Until you spend say a 6 months or maybe  year or 2 at this?

I would fork out the extra $2 for a windows hosting plan on go-daddy, and go with that. But, even then, you have to determine if that web server in question supports say .net core and you used .net core. Or if not, then what .net framework version did you use for development? If the web server does not have that framework, then you can't use that hosting plan. For example, the latest .net framework (non core) is version 4.8, but some web hosting plans only recent adopted and support .net 4.8. As a result, you have to use .net 4.5, or even maybe .net 4.0 for your development platform.

So, you MUST ALWAYS develop your software based on what software and systems EXIST on the target web server.

No such thing as "just publish" to any old web server EVER existed in our industry. How this works for desktop computers, or a web server computer box is not really different.

I should also point out that asp.net REQUIRES the IIS web server and NOT say Apache web server. So, then how can and does a .net core publish work on a Linux box running Apache web server?

Well, during your publish, you INCLUDE a IIS compatible web server. Then you configure Apache to FORWARD all requests to IIS (that low foot print web server is called Kestrel if you wondering).

So, not only will the .net core runtimes be required on that web server, but ALSO a working copy of IIS web server. It turns out that BOTH the .net core runtimes and the included IIS web server CAN be included as part of a .net core publish to a Linux web server. (and to be 100% clear, your server has to be running CentOS compatible version of Linux).

ONCE you do this publish, then you STILL have to configure Apache to FORWARD all requests to the IIS compatible web server.

Comment: People develop on platforms different from the one they deploy to all the time. There's plenty of tools such as VMs and WSL to help with that. And this question is for ASP.NET Core, so deploying .NET Framework wouldn't apply.

Comment: .net core is simple another .net runtime and a newer version of the .net runtime. Only diffrence is the .net core runtimes exist for more platforms then the previous versions of the .net frame work. And yes, you will need those .net core runtimes on target computer for this to work. And while we OFTEN develop on a different computer (as Homer Simpson would say - duh!!).  the simple matter is the dev tools you used and frameworks MUST and systems MUST exist and be installed and supported on the target server.  A simple web publish does not even get you remote close to this requirement.

Comment: Now, to try and keep this simple? There is a .net core publish option that includes the .net runtimes (the .net core ones). No matter how you slice this, the target computer will require the .net runtime - either the .net framework one, or the .net core one. As for the requirements and what kind of target box can support this setup is beyond this post.  but a minor correction? For .net framework runtimes, no such publish can install the .net framework for you. but for .net core runtimes, there is a publish option that will include the .net core runtime. So, not any old web server supports this

Comment: FYI: So, not only will the .net core runtimes be required on that web server, but ALSO a working copy of IIS web server. It turns out that BOTH the .net core runtimes and the included IIS web server CAN be included as part of a .net core publish to a Linux web server. (and to be 100% clear, your server has to be running CentOS compatible version of Linux).

ONCE you do this publish, then you STILL have to configure Apache to FORWARD all requests to the IIS compatible web server. (This means that Apache quite much acts like a port forward router box or proxy).

Comment: I feel like you're trying to convey info about every possible scenario instead of focusing on on what was asked. IIS is a Windows server tool. It's not on Linux. Perhaps you're confusing it with Kestrel, where the guidance has been to put a battle hardened web server in front  of it as as a proxy, such as Nginx or Apache?

Comment: Actually Kestrel is a full working copy of IIS. You are in fact running Internet information services web server when you do this. Apache is doing NOTHING more then simple forwarding incoming requests to that web server. After all, simple things like a config file to secure parts of the web site based say on a user security role? Apache has ZERO clue as to how IIS security and authentication is setup. information services is REQUIRED to run that asp.net site on that box.  Apache has zero clue as to what to do with an asp.net site with .net assemblies and .net code

Comment: Yes, I understand how proxies work. You're going to have to provide a source that proves your statement that Kestrel is a full working copy of IIS. If that were true, there would be no reason to proxy calls to it on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Well, you don't require Apache - but I just pointing out if you  ARE (and that is 99% of the cases WHEN purchasing web hosting - as per THIS question? Then yes, you simple have to setup Apache to forward the ports. but, if you NOT going to be running Apache (such as with go-daddy you ARE running Apache). sure, you don't need Apache and you don't need any proxy setup. Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: first off all thanks for your response, I was thinking that is easy to deploy .net core on linux server, but I was wrong

Comment: It is very easy if you have VM hosting plan.  For a low cost $9 web plan? No, since you often can't even do the correct configurating for that web site, but can only post + up-load say a KNOWN working Apache web site based on Linux code. As I stated, you can deploy rather easy to a Linux box  -- but you tend to need and require control and configuration of that remote server box. A low cost monthly plan from go-daddy does not allow you to do such configuring. As I stated, spend the extra $3.50 cents per month and go with a windows hosting plan from go-daddy, and you can just publish.